# SP with multiple criteria

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Suppose we have a directed G(V,E) graph with positive weights on it's edges.This graph's edges also are either black or green.Given a starting vertice u we need to find the minimum paths(in weight) from u to all vertices of V.These paths though must have at maximum k green edges(where k is a positive integer).Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting question! Maybe more about Math though than coding. Hence the question might be better suited on Mathoverflow or Mathstack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by creating `k + 1` graphs `G_i` consisting of copies of the vertices and the black edges:

- for every `v in V` you create `v_0, v_1, ... v_k`
- for every black edge `(u, v) in E` you create `(u_i, v_i)` for all `0 <= i <= k`

Each of these `G_i` represents the state after you have used `i` green edges already. So we can connect these graphs by adding the green edges:

- for every green `(u, v) in E` you create edge `(u_i, v_{i+1})` for all `0 <= i < k`.

The edges are directed so you cannot move "backwards", i.e., the number of green edges already used can never decrease.

Finally, add sink vertices:

- for every `v in V` you create `v_s` and edges `(v_i, v_s)` with *weight 0* for all `0 <= i <= k`.

These sink vertices allow is to determine the minimum distance to vertex `v` for every number of green vertices used.

---

Now, just run Dijkstra's with starting vertex `u_0`. For all `v in V`, the result for `v_s` is the shortest distance from `u` to `v` using at most `k` green edges.

---

The running time of Dijkstra's is `O(|E| + |V| log |V|)`. Our total number of vertices is `O(k) * |V|` and the total number of edges is `O(k) * |E|`, so the final running time is

```
O(k|E| + k|V| log k|V|)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!The graph is directed though.Is the solution still the same?

Comment: Even better @Leopardard, that simplifies it a bit. I updated the answer.